# how to check if the end of the user input end with "?' "." "!"

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

Get a new message from the user. Validate the message to make sure that it starts with a capital letter and ends with either a period ('.'), question mark ('?') or exclamation point ('!'). If the input is invalid, reject it with an error message to the user (keep using the prior message instead). Otherwise if valid replace the original message.

I check the first character that work, now to check the end of the string, I add the length of the input character to the input minus 1. but that change the value of the first character of the user input.

```
section .data
        text1 db "ENTER TEXT: "
        len equ $ - text1
        text2 db "THIS IS WHAT YOU ENTERED: "
        text3 db "invalid message, keeping curent "


section .bss
        character resb 255

section .text
        global main

main:
        mov r11, text2

        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, text1
        mov rdx, 12
        syscall
        call validate


validate:

         mov rax, 0
        mov rdi, 0
        mov rsi, character
        mov rdx, 10
        syscall                                                                                                                                                                
        mov r8, rax

        mov rdi, character
        mov al, [character]
        mov ah, 'A'
        cmp al, ah
        jl invalid

        cmp al, 90
        jg invalid

        add rax, r8             ;                                                                                                                                                                           
        sub rax, 1

        cmp rax, '!'
        je valid
        cmp rax, '.'
        je valid
        cmp rax, '?'
        je valid
valid:

        mov r11, character

        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, r11
        mov rdx, r8
        syscall
        jmp exit

invalid:

        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, text3
        mov rdx, 12
        syscall
        jmp exit

exit:

        mov rax, 60
        xor rdi, rdi
        syscall
```

Comment: You loaded the address into `rdi` not `rax`. Change that to `rax` and move the assignment to just before the `add`. Also, you need to fetch the character from memory, that is use `cmp byte [rax]` in your comparisons

Comment: You can check a character for being one of up-to-4 values using `movd xmm0, eax` / `pshufd xmm0,xmm0` (duplicate the byte to the bottom of each of 4 dwords).  Then `pcmpeqb xmm0, [rel compare_vector]` / `pmovmskb eax, xmm0` to get a bitmap compare result.  Then `test eax, 0x1111` to test the low element of each group of 4 to see if any of them were non-zero.  (x86-64 includes SSE2 as baseline).  Anyway, that answers the interesting title question, but not the debugging question, so I didn't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider simplifying your code and at the same time not altering users entry. SYSCALL has already returned the number of chars you've entered and RSI is unchanged.

```
mov  cl, [rsi]      ; RSI already points to first character
cmp  cl, 'A'
jb  invalid
cmp  cl, 'Z'
ja  invalid

mov  al, [rsi+rax-2]    ; RAX = # of characters entered

cmp  al, '.'
jz  valid
cmp  al, '?'
jz  valid
cmp  al, '!'
jnz Error
```

Now the leading character hasn't been changed and saving a few bytes by not unnecessarily setting other pointers.